# Disable "Confirm Form Resubmission" prompt on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to disable "Confirm Form Resubmission" popups on Google Chrome when I make a refresh. [This (very) old discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=21cf043a8f8e0098&hl=en) acknowledges the problem but doesn't provide a fix.

Is there someone out there with a better idea?

Comment: Download the Chrome source code and hack together your own version with all the features you do and don't want.

Comment: Like JSZ said in the discussion thread that Justin linked to, it is up to the **site** to handle re-visits (such as searches), not the browser to (impossibly) guess what is or is not a valid/safe automated resubmit.

Comment: from RFC 2616: *"This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested."*

Comment: @Moab Why so serious ? :p

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Chrome introduced this "feature" in order to avoid users unintentionally duplicating POST actions on forms, such as buying the same article twice.

This apparently was fixed some time ago by using the `-disable-prompt-on-repost` parameter on the Chrome invocation, but this also was broken in later versions. (*Edit: Reported as working again since 2020.*).

In spite of numerous related Chrome bug reports, that stayed open for years (!), the bug is still there. Apparently, the Chrome module that does back/forward is written so badly that it is almost impossible to fix. And nobody dares rewrite it from scratch.

Therefore, if you cannot modify the page containing the POST operation, then you are out of luck and there is no solution.

If you can modify the page, then you have two solutions :

1. Use GET instead of POST
2. Use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) method with the [HTTP 303](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) response code

There is of course the solution of using another browser than Chrome (but that doesn't answer the question).

Comment: Thanks. Could you please link to some of these bug reports?

Comment: Just use [this google query](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=pHg&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=%22Confirm+Form+Resubmission%22+chrome&oq=%22Confirm+Form+Resubmission%22+chrome&aq=f&aqi=g1g-m1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=92045l94122l0l95479l7l7l0l0l0l0l231l1305l0.5.2l7l0) that gives more than 8000 answers.

Comment: Technically, Chrome did not introduce this feature, it has been present in pretty much all web browsers for years (at *least* 15 or so).

Comment: Opera fortunately does not have this misfeature.

Comment: Just in case someone's looking for an answer: you've found it. This command line option works for me as of 2020.

Comment: How do you do this for mac?